# My edit was rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

My suggested edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972945/scala-execution-of-abstract-classes-with-case)
was rejected ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4140480)) and in my opinion it should not be so. I think that the main reason why the answer is right is because of this import that was deleted by the author of the answer. Actually, I am the author of the question and therefore the one that accepted the answer and also checked later that, without this import that was apparently accidentally deleted, it doesn't work.

Comment: Downvoting without explaining the reason is just too wrong.

Comment: @LuciaPasarin downvotes in meta work differently than in Stack Overflow. Downvotes indicate agreement or disagreement and not usefulness or lack of. I hope that explains it.

Comment: You wrote "got lost in the last edit" but the OP has removed it on purpose. It's not your (or anyone's) place to decide what code the author will post. You can post comment asking him why he removed it, not decide to just add it back. That is indeed an invalid edit.

Comment: Ok @BenjaminGruenbaum. Good to know that. I was just expecting a reply like: "I agree with the reviewer's decision" or "I don't agree".

Comment: @ShadowWizard thank you very much for your explanation. It was really helpful and I will keep it in mind the next time.

Comment: @LuciaPasarin the downvote probably means strong "I agree with the rejection", not mine though.

Comment: @LuciaPasarin Ok, in that case - I didn't downvote but I agree with the rejection. If you have a comment about original poster's code then leave a comment. Don't change the question, that could be really confusing for the original poster. Generally, it is considered rude to edit non community wiki question/answer code without consent from the original poster. Think of it as someone pushing code into your git repo without you giving them commit access.

Comment: Ok. Now it's clear. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewers reject code edits because they have some misgiven ideas about what an appropriate edit is. Today's proponent of this is [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222675/my-edit-was-rejected#comment724532_222675):

> It's not your (or anyone's) place to decide what code the author will post. You can post comment asking him why he removed it, not decide to just add it back. That is indeed an invalid edit.

This opinion, while popular, is wrong. Your edit should not have been rejected, and I have made it for you. You asked the question, you checked the code, it didn't work without this library, so you added it. This is correct behavior. You can read more [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200336/), but the same is written in the guidance on how to use Stack Overflow.

The [about page says](https://stackoverflow.com/about):

> ### Improve posts by editing or commenting
>
> Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them.
>
> **Use edits to fix mistakes**, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post.

The [edit page says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> ### When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you see a post that needs improvement and are inclined to
> suggest an edit, you are welcome to do so. The original author of a
> question or answer may always edit their own post, regardless of
> reputation level.
>
> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
> you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - **To correct minor mistakes** or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

Comment: This looks fine to me. Finally the author's edit was right. The deleted part wasn't required for the case that he replied but for my final version after adapting my code according to his answer and my own needs, it ends up being a crucial one, and this is why I confused. Everything is clear now and I also have a better understanding on how and when to edit posts.